# Twitter Bootstrap glyphicon shows 'greater than' sign instead of the glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following simple bit of code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="foo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>Foo:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <span id="foo">Barr</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of seeing the question mark sign, it comes up with a greater than sign (>). I tried changing it to other glyphicons, such as the info sign, and that became the "less than, or equal to" sign.

Has anyone hit this issue before? Any hints would be appreciated.

Bootstrap version: 3.1.1

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Just tried then, no luck. I've also tried viewing the page in firefox (currently developing in chrome) and it shows the same thing. I'd never opened that page up in firefox before, so it wouldn't have any issues with cached data I would suspect. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was.
I had the twitter bootstrap 'fonts' folder not sitting under the 'css' folder. Not sure why I had originally thought ages ago that I could move it out! Still, i find it weird that it would display funny symbols if they didn't exist.

Thanks for the help that was offered.